# qt slider problem c++

Tags: c++, qt

the following code plays the song while a button is pressed (`onclick`). I have created a `horizontalSlider` UI but it is not sliding. I got the document from http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Streaming_Audio_with_Qt

Please help me to make the slider work.

```
Phonon::MediaObject *mediaObject = new Phonon::MediaObject(this);

Phonon::AudioOutput *audioOutput =
new Phonon::AudioOutput(Phonon::MusicCategory, this);

Phonon::createPath(mediaObject, audioOutput);

const QString url("c://example.mp3");

mediaObject->setCurrentSource(url);

mediaObject->play();

volumeSlider = new Phonon::VolumeSlider(ui->horizontalSlider);
volumeSlider->setAudioOutput(audioOutput);
volumeSlider->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Maximum, QSizePolicy::Maximum);
```

Comment: You expect the horizontalSlider to do anything? Am I mistaken when I say you simply made it the parent of the volumeSlider? There is no functional relationship that I see between the horizontalSlider and the volumeSlider...

Answer (score 1):

Probably you didn't bind the corresponding media object to the slider.

*See a small example [here.](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/phonon-seekslider.html#details)*

Comment: i got it works but if i use Phonon::SeekSlider *slider = new Phonon::SeekSlider;
     slider->setMediaObject(moo);

     slider->show(); it loads in seperate window how can i bind it to my same UI windo???

Comment: pass it as parent to the constructor of slider